# fullpage.js disabling auto scrolling changes page width

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

when I have auto scrolling enabled page is being rendered fine, but after I disable it, page width is changed.

Here's a screen with autoscrolling enabled:

[image]

Screens with autoscrolling disabled:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, I can scroll horizontally. How can I fix it?
Screen from mobile device:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't sound like an issue with fullpage.js, but more related with your CSS stylesheet. In fact, you can not reproduce it in [this example page](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/methods.html) turning autoScrolling off. A link to the reproduction of the issue would help, and ideally in an isolated environment such as jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: Check this, the more pages I add, more it gets stretched. https://imgur.com/a/cVKbb

Comment: You are definitively doing something wrong. Check your HTML.

Comment: Sure, I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't understand what it is. If I have autoScrolling enabled, then everything works just fine, but after I disable it something gets wrong. autoScrolling false shouldn't just enable normal scrolling? What else does it change?

Comment: I fixed that issue, but now I have another one. When I have autoScrolling disabled, I want page not to be responsive when height is changing. Here are some examples: https://i.imgur.com/RZYWpJL.png https://i.imgur.com/f8LGjA0.png

As you can see on the second image, when I change height, section gets automatically stretched, but I don't want that, instead of that I want on that height two sections to be shown.